# Calculating the outward surface normal of a mesh cone plane

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, normals

I've created a mesh cone:

[image]

With points that are oriented as such:

```
    p3
   /   
  /
 p1 ---- p2
```

I've calculate u = p2 - p1, v = p3 - p1
and then take the cross product u X v and normalize the vector before taking its perspective projection. But no matter which way I calculate u and v (e.g. u = p2 - p1, v = p3 - p2) my normals always face towards the inside of the cone.

I've looked at many other examples on here but none of them seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Edit - This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I've run the numbers through a vector calculator and all the calculations are correct.

One of the planes:

```
P1x: 0.866025
P1y: -0.500000
P1z: 9.000000

P2x: 0.939693
P2y: -0.342020
P2z: 9.000000

P3x: 0.000000
P3y: -0.000000
P3z: 10.000000

Vector U: 0.073667, 0.157980, 0.000000
Vector V: -0.866025, 0.500000, 1.000000
Normal: 0.157980, -0.073667, 0.173648
```

My code for calculating u, v, and n is:

```
            //u = p2 - p1
            vecU.m[1][1] = p2.m[1][1] - p1.m[1][1];
            vecU.m[2][1] = p2.m[2][1] - p1.m[2][1];
            vecU.m[3][1] = p1.m[3][1] - p1.m[3][1];
            vecU.m[4][1] = 1;

            printf("Vector U: %f, %f, %f\n", vecU.m[1][1], vecU.m[2][1], vecU.m[3][1]);

            //v = p3 - p1
            vecV.m[1][1] = p3.m[1][1] - p1.m[1][1];
            vecV.m[2][1] = p3.m[2][1] - p1.m[2][1];
            vecV.m[3][1] = p3.m[3][1] - p1.m[3][1];
            vecV.m[4][1] = 1;

            printf("Vector V: %f, %f, %f\n", vecV.m[1][1], vecV.m[2][1], vecV.m[3][1]);

            //n = u X v
            vecN.m[1][1] = (vecU.m[2][1] * vecV.m[3][1]) - (vecU.m[3][1] * vecV.m[2][1]);
            vecN.m[2][1] = (vecU.m[3][1] * vecV.m[1][1]) - (vecU.m[1][1] * vecV.m[3][1]);
            vecN.m[3][1] = (vecU.m[1][1] * vecV.m[2][1]) - (vecU.m[2][1] * vecV.m[1][1]);
            vecN.m[4][1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer ist switching u and v in the cross product, but I guess your question is rather something like "how do I determine if i just calculated the normal in the correct direction"? That should be determined by saving vertices counter-clockwise.

### After seeing your edit:

I can't see an error in your calculations, but your drawing does not look like normals at all. It's not just about the sign of the normal, but you seem to just always point to the center of the ground surface of your cone.

I can't really say any more without seeing the actual code. Do all of your 'normals' in fact point to a single point?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that combination as well and still no luck. I'm not saving my vertices - I just calculate them, calculate the normal then draw them right away and move on to the next... although I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: If reversing the cross product order does not solve your problem, then your problem is not one of inward-pointing normals. It must be something else.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I've added details and code to the question.

Comment: Is it the way I'm drawing it maybe? The vector starts at the origin. I need it to start at the surface itself.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I translated the surface normal vector so that it began at p1. VecNx += p1x etc. What was happening was the normal vectors were starting at the origin and then ending at the point those lines began.

Now they start at p1 and end outside of the surface. Thanks for your help guys.